# Cannot navigate to route when default route has a parameter in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I have the following routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BlogLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':pageNumber',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'article/:id',
        component: ArticleComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'articles-by-hashtag/:id',
        component: ArticlesByHashComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'articles-by-category/:id',
        component: ArticlesByCatComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'about-me',
        component: AboutMeComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

All the routes work fine, but I cannot navigate to the `about-me` page using `routerLink` like so:

```
<li><a [routerLink]="[ 'about-me' ]">ABOUT ME</a></li>
```

If I remove the default parameter `:pageNumber` then the navigation works, else the `about-me` link take me to the default route.

How can I make the `about-me` route work? I'd rather not use `router.navigate(...` to be honest.

Comment: Try this [routerLink]="[ '/about-me' ]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change your route like this

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['/about-me']">ABOUT ME</a></li>
```

Then add some route before the pageNumber params. I'm not sure your route defenition for HomeComponent is correct

```
{
   path: 'something/:pageNumber',
   component: HomeComponent
},
```